# Dimension of homology of groups

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I am troubles when understanding why the following holds: Let $G$ be a group and $p\colon G \mapsto H$ a surjective homomorphism. Then, if $H_{1}(G, \mathbb{Q})$ is finite dimensional, so is $H_{1}(H,\mathbb{Q})$.

Can someone tell me from where does this derive? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H_1(G,\mathbb{Z})=G/[G,G]$, thus if $f$ is surjective it induces a surjection

$G/[G,G]\rightarrow H/[H,H]=H_1(H,\mathbb{Z})$.

Use the fact that $H_1(G,\mathbb{Q})=H_1(\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I didn't realise that the first homology is the abelianization! haha Thank you!! So, if $i\geq 2$, you can't say straightforward that if $H_{i}(G,\mathbb{Q})$ is finite dimensional, is $H_{i}(H,\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: Its false if $i \ge 2$. Start with a group where $H_i(H,\mathbb Q)$ is not finite dimensional, pick a generating set $\{h_i\}_{i \in I}$ for $H$, let $F_I$ be the corresponding free group whose higher dimensional homologies are all trivial, and take the corresponding surjective homomorphism $F_I \mapsto H$.